# Распознавание лиц Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Необходимо написать программу для распознавания лиц на фотографиях, и по идентифицированным лицам осуществить сортировку фото. Стоит ли использовать OpenCV, как хранить опознанные лица в базе. С чего начать?

Comment: openCV да стоит. И нужно уточнить вы 2D или 3D распознование деалть собираетесь? Начать с изучения OpenCV там уже из коробки он умеет лица находить.

Comment: Еще нужно придумать алгоритм как вы сыобираетесь сопостовлять лица и сортировать.